# For a set of (installed) R packages how can I find out if all dependencies are at least minimum required versions for the given setup?

Tags: r, dependencies, remotes

I'm running a somewhat tight ship in regard to available libraries in my docker based R setup.
Thus, package updates are performed conservatively and consciously. New versions are more or less
hand picked. In this context I realised that incrementing a package's version will not complain in
regard to outdated dependencies if the dependency is already installed in a smaller version than is actually required.

An example is shown below to demonstrate what I mean. The example was created on a "clean" `R 4.1.2` without any packages installed except for the ones that come directly with R.

I'm aware that the paramter settings `dependencies = FALSE` and `upgrade = "never"` prevent installing/upgrading dependencies (I need these settings for stringent control), however, I would have expected at least a warning telling me that e.g. `askpass 1.2.0` requires at least `sys 2.1` or equivalently that `highr 0.10` requires at least `xfun 0.18`.

Presumably problems will only start showing up on runtime of certain features, which I would like to prevent.

Is there a clever way handle this?

```r
install.packages("remotes", dependencies = FALSE) # 2.4.2.1

remotes::install_version("sys",
                         version = "2.0",
                         dependencies = FALSE,
                         upgrade = "never")
remotes::install_version("askpass",
                         version = "1.2.0",
                         dependencies = FALSE,
                         upgrade = "never")

remotes::install_version("xfun",
                         version = "0.17",
                         dependencies = FALSE,
                         upgrade = "never")
remotes::install_version("highr",
                         version = "0.10",
                         dependencies = FALSE,
                         upgrade = "never")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies as "clever" but at least it returns the required information to remedy outdated dependencies problem.

```r
# these packages do not interfere with the
# example but are required to run the below code
#install.packages("dplyr")
#install.packages("purrr")
#install.packages("stringr")

library(dplyr) # 1.1.3
library(purrr) # 1.0.2
library(stringr) # 1.5.0

inst_packs <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())

inst_packs_name_version <- inst_packs %>%
  select(Package, Version)

# single vector
dependency_info <- unlist(strsplit(c(inst_packs$Depends,
                                     inst_packs$Imports,
                                     inst_packs$LinkingTo),
                                   split = ",",
                                   fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  str_squish() %>%
  unique() %>%
  discard(is.na)

splits <- strsplit(dependency_info, split = "\\(")

package <- str_squish(as.character(map(splits, 1)))
version <- gsub(x = as.character(map(splits, 2)),
                pattern = "[^0-9.-]",
                replacement = "")

deps <- data.frame(Package = package, Version = version) %>%
  # highest Version is up top
  arrange(Package, desc(Version)) %>%
  # dependencies without version do not need to be considered
  # also R is not a relevant dependency here
  filter(Version != "" & Package != "R")

deps_uniq <- deps[!duplicated(deps$Package), ] %>%
  arrange(Package)
row.names(deps_uniq) <- NULL

relevant_installed <- inst_packs_name_version %>%
  filter(Package %in% deps_uniq$Package) %>%
  arrange(Package, desc(Version))
# base R packages that are installed by the user too appear more than once
# e.g. "Matrix", "survival"
relevant_installed_uniq <- relevant_installed[!duplicated(relevant_installed$Package),]

row.names(relevant_installed_uniq) <- NULL

# sanity check
if(! all(deps_uniq$Package == relevant_installed_uniq$Package)) {
  stop("Different set of packages. Assumptions are not met.")
}

reference_df <- data.frame(Package = deps_uniq$Package,
                           Version_req = deps_uniq$Version,
                           Version_inst = relevant_installed_uniq$Version)

# show only packages where a later version than the installed one is required
reference_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(req_larger_inst = compareVersion(Version_req, Version_inst)) %>%
  filter(req_larger_inst > 0)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  Package Version_req Version_inst req_larger_inst
  <chr>   <chr>       <chr>                  <dbl>
1 sys     2.1         2.0                        1
2 xfun    0.18        0.17                       1
```